# Emma com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [CLASS_STAMP_MISMATCH]

Tags: emma, runtimeexception

Okay, Emma is killing me. I spent two days on this already.

There two issues with Emma now

1. It crashes partly  through unit testing
2. It complaints about class stamp mismatch. : `com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [CLASS_STAMP_MISMATCH] runtime version of class xxx in the coverage data is not consistent with the version of this class in the metadata, possibly because stale metadata is being used for report generation`.

While I can live with the crashes, it only often but I don't intent to fix it,

> INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
>        [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0

However, I do like to see my coverage result.

I have tried:

1. clean the device
2. wiped out entire workspace (in Jenkins)
3. using the command prompt (bypass jenkins, ant clean, ant emma debug install test)

My understanding of this error is the apk installed and under unit test contains different binaries and hence its metadata info is out of date with the coverage.em generated.

I can confirm this is IMPOSSIBLE in my case, as I clead, ant clean and even wiped out entire work space and the phone memory. It just doesn't make any sense to me now.

Please HELP~

I am using Android sdk r16, NDK 5c, and the default settings from Ant and Emma.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the exact same problem with my Android project (which uses a native code third-party library via JNI). It turns out that the EMMA error message is slightly misleading in this case. It's triggered because the statically generated coverage meta-data on the host (coverage.em) does not match the coverage data collected during run-time of the application on the device (coverage.ec). In fact, it's not only a "mismatch", but the coverage.ec is completely missing. This is due to the crash in native code: On Android, a crash in native code will shut down the associated Java process, too, and in fact even restart the VM. This means EMMA is killed, too, and it does not have chance to flush the coverage.ec file to disk any more, which is why it's missing.

I've wondered whether it would make sense to make EMMA flush the coverage.ec file more often before the crash, but then again it's questionable how valuable an incomplete coverage info would be as

1. the file format probably is just not build in a way that makes sense to be parsed incrementally,
2. a partial coverage.ec still would mismatch a complete coverage.em,
3. coverage generated from a partial coverage.ec would report the wrong coverage with respect to all your tests in the suite.

So, long story short, the best way to address this is to fix your native code to not crash.

Answer (score 0):

I met with this problem too when using EMMA for android. It's because the coverage.ec you pull from sdcard is not consistent with coverage.em. Try rebuild the instrumented version of the project.
Try the following steps:

1. ant clean release
2. ant instrument
3. ant installi
4. adb pull /mnt/sdcard/coverage.ec
5. use the coverage.em ( newly generated under the bin folder of the project through step 2 ) and coverage.ec to generate the coverage report

You can refer to [EMMA for Android](http://clasnake.net/emma_for_android/) for detailed information.